# How to model the effect of 2 predictor variables in a paired linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a dataset formed of `Patient_ID`, `Lesion_ID`, `Treatment_Outcome`, `Treatment_Administrated_1`, `Chemotherapy`. `Chemotherapy` is a binary variable `yes/no`, while the `Treatment_Administrated_1` is a continuous variable. Both of these are different treatments, however `Chemotherapy` is administered per `Patient_ID`, while `Treatment_Administrated_1` is administered per `Lesion_ID`.

I looked into mixed linear effects models and it seems to be what I am looking for, however, I am not sure if this is the right method and if it is if I applied correctly.

Here is a sample of my data in Excel format: https://send.firefox.com/download/540795a98e449e65/#dvAW3yalIh8zK77-kH9fYA

Here is the code:

```
library(lsmeans)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(lme4)
radiomics <- read_excel("example_chemo.xlsx")
radiomics$EAV <- radiomics$`Treatment_Outcome`
radiomics$PAV <- radiomics$`Treatment_Administered_1`

m.interaction <- lmer(EAV ~ PAV*Chemotherapy + (1|Patient_ID), data = radiomics)
library(interactions)
interact_plot(m.interaction, pred = PAV, modx = Chemotherapy, interval = TRUE)
anova(m.interaction)
summary(m.interaction)

# Obtain slopes ------------------------------------------------------------------
m.interaction$coefficients
m.lst <- lstrends(m.interaction, "Chemotherapy", var="PAV")
print(m.lst)
# Compare slopes ------------------------------------------------------------------
pairs(m.lst)
m.correlations <- radiomics[, cor(EAV, PAV), by=Chemotherapy]
```

[image]

**How do I study the linear relationship between `Treatment_Outcome` (response variable) and `Treatment_Administrated_1`, given the influence of `Chemotherapy = yes/no` and how I would report these values?**

Comment: may I suggest that the effect of PAV may not be linear? why else would EAV be better, at PAV = 0, for those who do chemo?

Comment: PAV is never 0. The effect can be non-linear.

Comment: what's the meaning of PAV? how much it is in case of no treatment? what are the values occurring in the dataset?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I study the linear relationship between `Treatment_Outcome` (response variable) and `Treatment_Administrated_1`, given the influence of `Chemotherapy = yes/no` and how I would report these values?

You have made a good start. There seems, however, to be no single "linear relationship between `Treatment_Outcome` [`EAV`] (response variable) and `Treatment_Administrated_1` [`PAV`]" when `Chemotherapy` is taken into account. According to your plot it seems that, with chemotherapy, PAV doesn't matter but, absent chemotherapy, it does. To document that, show the table of results documenting the significant `PAV:Chemotherapy` interaction term and display a plot like what you show here.

Your model does not include your `Lesion_ID`. That might be OK, depending on the design. For example if `EAV` is measured per patient then `Lesion_ID` probably has nothing to do with outcome. If it's measured lesion-by-lesion, and particularly if PAV is also administered lesion-by-lesion, however, then you might need to take `Lesion_ID` into account too (being careful either to have no Lesions with the same ID among patients, or specifying that `Lesion_ID` is nested within `Patient_ID`).

There are a couple of more things to consider. The first has to do with the specification of the random effects term, particularly if your model has to incorporate `Lesion_ID`. As it stands now, it's pretty simple: each Patient is allowed a different value of the Intercept at a hypothetical condition of PAV=0 and the baseline level you specified for `Chemotherapy`. The distribution of Intercepts is taken to be Gaussian. There's no allowance for different slopes of the `EAV`/`PAV` relationship among Patients. Think carefully about if that's what you really intend. If you add `Lesion_ID` as a similar random effect (effectively nested under `Patient_ID`) then you are further specifying a distribution of Intercept differences around the corresponding `Patient_ID` Intercept for the Lesions within a Patient.

Second, and maybe more critical, are the other clinical variables that might be hiding within the `Chemotherapy` and `PAV` values. Unless this was a controlled clinical trial, the decision to administer `Chemotherapy` was presumably based on a set of clinical and pathological observations that aren't incorporated in your model. Similar considerations might apply to the choice of `PAV` administered. If any of those other variables are associated themselves with `EAV`then there is a serious risk of [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) and of potential misinterpretation of the clinical significance of your findings.